# The fourth pillar of mathematics? (analysis, algebra, geometry and ...)

Tags: soft-question, education

Many universities claim that there are three general areas in mathematics: **analysis**, which deals with continuous aspects of mathematics; **algebra**, which deals with discrete aspects; and **geometry**.

If you were to chose the *fourth*, what would it be?

Comment: Combinatorics?!

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: it is algebra.

Comment: This is *very* opinion-based.

Comment: physics seems like math

Comment: I always thought that topology and set theory counted as general areas. But indeed, this is very opinion based.

Comment: @IvoTerek: Topology falls into analysis, because topology is a study of continuity.

Comment: Foundations? (Includes mathematical logic, axiomatic set theory, constructivism, etc.)

Comment: @Graduate  I didn't knew it. Thanks (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia lists [four ideas on which pure mathematics focuses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics#Pure_mathematics):

- Quantity
- Structure
- Space
- Change

The second, third, and fourth categories seem to match your labels of algebra, geometry, and analysis, respectively. The first could probably be labeled number theory, but Wikipedia also lists number theory as studying structure (so perhaps "quantity" shouldn't really be a separate category?). If the quantity category were to be kept, it could correspond to arithmetic. However, it seems demeaning to analysis/geometry/algebra to elevate arithmetic to a "pillar of mathematics".

Since this is quite a subjective question, the words of whoever wrote that section of the article are not fact. Neither are my opinions particularly supported by ethos.